# SQL Error: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis when trying to creating table

Tags: sql, oracle

This is the query I am trying to execute against an Oracle database which apparently has no parenthesis missing.

```
CREATE TABLE P_DOG(
DOG_ID CHAR(5) NOT NULL,
DOG_NAME VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'UNKNOWN',
DOG_BIRTHDAY_MONTH NUMBER(2) NULL CHECK(DOG_BIRTH_MONTH>=1 AND DOG_BIRTH_MONTH<=12),
DOG_BIRTHDAY_YEAR NUMBER(4) NOT NULL CHECK(DOG_BIRTH_YEAR>=1980 AND DOG_BIRTH_YEAR<= 2030),
SEX CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
SPAYED_OR_NEUTERED CHAR(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
CONSTRAINT DOG_PK PRIMARY KEY(DOG_ID),
);
```

Comment: Extra `,` at the end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides the extra comma at the end that Mat pointed out in a comment, NOT NULL should come after the defaults - and the check constraints should have the correct column names: the column names have BIRTHDAY but the conditions use BIRTH, change either the column name or what you have in the conditions so they match.

Specifically the "missing right parenthesis" error is caused by having a DEFAULT after NOT NULL. Wrong order.

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH! THAT HELPS!